# Getting indexes of elements of an array with certain values

Tags: f#

Consider I have an array of options like `[|Some 1;Some0;None;None;Some0|]`
and i am going to get the indexes of elements with `None` value, in this case the correct answer would be `[|2;3|]`.

My current idea is to change the array to a list and then go throw it using recursive function but in this case i will need `mutable value` to compute index, and i do not want to use mutable?

Is there any other solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
[|Some 1;Some 0;None;None;Some 0|]
    |> Array.indexed
    |> Array.filter (fun (i, x) -> x.IsNone)
    |> Array.map fst
```

As an optimization last 2 lines can be replaced by a single `|> Array.choose (function (i, None) -> Some i | _ -> None)`.

And here's another way using sequence expressions:

```
let x = [|Some 1;Some 0;None;None;Some 0|]
[|for i = 0 to x.Length-1 do
     if x.[i].IsNone then yield i|]
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about this **indexed** method